# Euclidean Distance Extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-10.3

I have a basemap w/ GPS points on it, and polygons of certain areas.  The polygons fall well within the borders of the basemap.  I am trying to generate a Euclidean Distance map of distance to these polygons, with the ENTIRE basemap as the Processing Environment.  The problem I keep running into is that the Euclidean Distance generates a map that only covers the **absolute** (x,y) extent of the polygon files.  I have tried setting the processing extent as the entire basemap, converting the polygon file to a raster with the basemap as the extent.....to no avail.

How do I generate a Euclidean distance map that goes **beyond** the input feature extent?

Comment: Kind of a workaround, but why don't you try just modifying your polygon layer to have the extents you wish to see in the output?

Comment: I tried setting a new extent (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/15671), but got error codes 010244 (could not set the analysis mapping window. Distance mapping is failed) and 010067 (error in executing grid expression) when I tried Euclidean distance.

Comment: Okay never mind all that then.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Geoprocessing functions like that can often be constrained to the OUTPUT EXTENT environment setting.

See this resource for ArcGIS 10.
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000

All you need to do is set the OUTPUT EXTENT to the desired extents.

Comment: I've tried that to no avail.  I get the same errors as above.  I've tried to set the extent to the basemap, and by manually entering bounding coordinates....

Answer (score 0):

This resource for ArcGIS 10 will give you all the information you need, but it's a little confusing if you aren't working on a stand-alone script.
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000

You can also modify the processing extent for all geoprocessing tools while working in ArcMap by going to "Geoprocessing > Environments" to open the environment settings. Then, under processing extent you are able to specify exactly what the processing extent should be.

[image]